# Tag merge request: links, hyperlink, permalink, broken-link, linking

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

[hyperlink](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyperlink) x 2

[linking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linking) x 3

[permalink](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permalink) x 4

[broken-link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-link) x 3

All of these are the same variation of [links](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/links) ( 23 questions)

Can these be merged & maybe a synonym can be created for these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The merges are complete.
The tag [links](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/links) is now the master tag.